# Is std::ostringstream thread safe for Embarcadero C++ Builder XE4?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, std, c++builder-xe4

I have an application that is throwing exceptions when my program terminates. I have the following utility function in a header file for converting numeric types to `std::strings` that I use to avoid my code being littered with `std::ostringstream` instances

```
namespace MyUtils {

    template <typename T>
    std::string NumericToString(const T& value)
    {
        std::string str_retval = "";
        try
        {
            std::ostringstream ost;
            ost << value;
            str_retval = ost.str();
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            str_retval = "?";
        }
        return str_retval;
    }   
}
```

Now this code is called from multiple threads and is called often and it is occaisonally throwing an access violation exception deep inside the ostringstream implementation. From what I can see of this code I can see no obvious reason why it is not thread safe.

I use an identical function inside other applications that I develop specifically for Linux (g++ 4.6.3) and I have never seen the code throw.

I know that thread safety inside the standard library should never be assumed, but my function is pretty basic. My application is built as a 64-bit application so it is making use of the C++11 compiler that ships with this version of XE4.

Can anyone tell me if there is any reason why my above function is unsafe, or indeed if there are any known issues with the Embarcadero C++ builder XE4 implementation of the standard library that makes this an unsafe thing to do?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you should assume that all standard library facilities are not thread-safe unless explicitly specified by the standard. However I don't see how this particular piece of code could have an issue.

Comment: Are you using static linking or dynamic linking? (Older versions of C++B had a bug where sometimes ostreams gave AVs if you used dynamic RTL).  Have you ever caught one of these AVs while in the debugger? (If so then you may get a clue from the stack trace)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Static linking is used. I have managed to catch one in the debugger but it ends up deep in the std::ostringstream code and I get a debugger detatch error at certain points. I recently discovered that Embarcadero boost::date_time library is not thread safe (in their build anyway) so I have had to give up using that. If I cannot even create thread local stringstream objects though, I am not sure what I have faith in working anymore...

Comment: When you stop in the debugger, go back through the stack trace and see if anything looks odd.  It's going to be hard to debug further unless you can come up with something that lets others reproduce the problem.